# Playa tag outputting relative fields in multiples

Tags: add-on, channel-entries

I have the following code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
<div class="row related-articles">
    <div class="grid_12">
        <h2>Related Articles</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled inline">
            {exp:playa:children entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                {cf_general_related}
                <li class="grid_3 alpha omega">
                    <h3>{title}</h3>
                    <img src="#" alt="#"/>
                    <span class="clear"></span>
                </li>
                {/cf_general_related}
            {/exp:playa:children}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The problem I'm finding here is, my related entries are outputting in multiples, so if I have 2 relative entries, I get 4 results in the template, if I have 4 relative entries, I get 16 items output. And each item repeats so many times.

Why?

Comment: What's the name of your playa field? What happens if you remove `{exp:playa:children entry_id="{entry_id}"}` and `{/exp:playa:children}`?

Comment: Is `{cf_general_related}` the name of your Playa field in your Blog channel?

Comment: Please make sure to select your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is sorted now. It turns out I only needed to update Playa to the latest version, and all my troubles disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting duplicate content cause playa is being called twice

First by (the direct call to the playa module)

```
{exp:playa:children field="cf_general_related"}
```

Secondly by (the field name tag pair option)

```
{cf_general_related}
    <li>..</li>
{/cf_general_related}
```

which produces

```
{exp:playa:children field="cf_general_related" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

I prefer field name tag pair (keeps the template clean)

```
{cf_general_related}{/cf_general_related}
```

*assuming that your playa field is {cf_general_related}

P.S. Upgrade to the latest version of Playa as there are some issues that have been addressed, one annoying one is

> -Fixed a bug where closing Playa module tags would show up on the front
>   end of the site

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your entry something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="fact_sheets" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination" }

 {exp:playa:children field="press_photos" }

      {if full_size_photo == ""}

         <img src="{press_thumbnail}" alt="{title}" />

      {if:else}

         <a href="{full_size_photo}"><img src="{press_thumbnail}" alt="{title}" /></a>

      {/if}

         <p>{caption}</p>

  {/exp:playa:children}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You pull the entry in with the channel entries and you reference the field in the Playa tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you nested 2 playa tags:

```
{exp:playa:children entry_id="{entry_id}"}
{cf_general_related}
```

The corrected syntax is:

```
{exp:playa:children field="cf_general_related"}
    <li>...</li>
{/exp:playa:children}
```

**You can find more info in the docs:**
http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates#playa:children

**EDIT:**

Seems like you're just trying to get the related fields of your entry.
All you need to do is this:

```
{cf_general_related}
    <li>..</li>
{/cf_general_related}
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the title's and data for the item itself, as passed in entry_id, and not the related items as expected?

Comment: take a look at my updated answer, that should do it.